# GeoMashup plugin: how to customize cluster markers / icons?

Tags: plugins, customization, javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to customize the standard cluster icon marker which GeoMashup uses to display nearby posts grouped in a certain area?

By default it's a red dot in V2, or a blue dot in V3. I nee to customize its appearance and replace it with a background/image?

Comment: I am not going to explain all the JS code, but did you tried to simply EDIT those images (leaving the same name/path) ?? if you want a BIGGER image , you will need to go to the JS code and change the values.

Comment: mmm if you're suggesting changing a bitmap image loaded locally by GeoMashup no that wouldn't work for the cluster marker because as I figured out later the cluster marker is not handled by GeoMashup directly; probably has to be filtered with json client side because it's loaded by Google itself from a GeoMashup javascript file; for now I hacked that GeoMashup JS file to alter size/color of the marker. If this is what you really intended well then it's what I ended up doing :)

Comment: yes, that is what i intended- in all my website i load GeoMashup LOCALLY. and change the values for the bitmap as well as the SIZE which is important .

Comment: GeoMashup is really a powerful and nice plugin but somehow it has quite a steep curve when it comes to customisation. Do you know any good alternative, even $$$ paid ones, that has similar functions but it's easier to customise when it comes to markers, legend or extending functionalities?

Comment: yws, I do know one . It is one that I wrote myself. But I have never released it to the wild . But more and more people are asking for this, so If I will find time in the next few days, or even today, I will do so and will let you know somehow.

Comment: what can I say, wow :) if you plan to make it open, you could open a repo on github - I have some customisation done for GeoMashup for custom markers according to post types and custom taxonomies, I plan to release that as well

Comment: Yws, any updates on your plugin?

Comment: yep.. if you want I have a beta . send me a mail and I can send it for you to test ..

Comment: cool, I've just sent an email to you using the contact form from your website

Comment: I did not see any mail (or maybe i missed it in spam) please send again to the address in my profile here - and specify in the title "about gmap plugin" or something similar...

Comment: krembo, I think I did receive a confirmation email upon submitting the form. Anyway, I tried to look for your email address in stackexchange profile, but I coudln't find any. How to contact members on stackexchange privately? is there another way to know your email address or contact you somewhere else? thanks

Comment: @Fluvio - hehe - I did not said you did not sent the mail :-) , I said I might have accidently deleted it like spam. anyhow, clicking on my profile name in stackexchange should give you my details with mail. and if not - the mail is my SE username at yahoo com

Comment: ok thanks, I did send an email now to the specified address; clicking on your profile name or picture in stackexchange, only redirects me to your profile page on stackexchange itself...

Comment: hi there, did message you long time ago :) still on a train? :D